# Cómo puedo enviar los datos a otra página

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo una pagina de venta de productos, en la página principal tengo los datos mostrados con cards de bootstrap. Y al darle click quiero que me direccione a una nueva pagina donde se muestra el detalle del producto, pero cómo envío los datos del producto a esa otra página?

Esta es mi sección donde muestro los productos

```
<?php
$product = "SELECT id_producto, nombre_producto, descripcion_producto, precio_producto, imagen_producto, id_properso FROM PRODUCTO";
$rproduct = $con -> query($product);
?>
<section class="content" id="muestraproducto">
   <div class="containter-fluid" id="modulo_producto">
      <div class="row">
      <?php while($rowpro = $rproduct->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ ?>
         <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="card <?php if($rowpro['id_properso'] != NULL || $row['id_properso'] != ''){ echo "card-outline card-warning";}?>">
               <a href="#" id="btneditFotopro" value="<?php echo $rowpro['id_producto']; ?>">
                  <img class="card-img-top" src="../data/bodega/Productos/<?php if($rowpro['imagen_producto'] == NULL){echo 'default.png';}else{echo $rowpro['imagen_producto'];}?>" onmouseout="this.src='../data/bodega/Productos/<?php if($rowpro['imagen_producto'] == NULL){echo 'default.png';}else{echo $rowpro['imagen_producto'];}?>';" onmouseover="this.src='../assets/img/edit.png';">
               </a>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title"><strong><?php echo $rowpro['nombre_producto'] ?></strong></h5>
                  <p class="card-text" style="font-size:15px">
                     <?php echo $rowpro['descripcion_producto'] ?>
                     </br>
                     <h5><span class="badge badge-info">Q.<?php echo $rowpro['precio_producto'];?>.00</span></h5>
                  </p>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <?php } ?>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hola, por que necesitas los datos del producto a la nueva seccion??

Comment: depende como estes haciendo la web hay muchas formas de pasar datos: por URL, por POST o por GET ...

Comment: si no conoces sobre el tema te sugiero que investigues o tomes un tutorial de como implementar el envio de datos por los metodos que te mencione

Comment: si yo te preguntara que has hecho, es por que para poder ayduarte necesito ver que has hecho en para lograr el objetivo; ya que el codigo que muestra, como dices solo muestra los cards...

Comment: te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Comment: Hola @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent Muchas gracias por contestar, me interesa hacer esto porque deseo que a la hora de cliquear el producto, muestre el detalle de producto, pero para no hacer una pagina por cada producto, que se envíe todo a una página.

Comment: muy bien ese principio es el correcto; eso se le llama plantillas pero para que eso funciones necesitas aprender a enviar datos de un html a otro como te los mencione y tambien a usar un html como plantilla ... crees que lo puedas investigar... una vez que lo hagas y que comiences a escribir ese codigo vienes actualizas tu pregunta o creas una nueva y te damos la mano, saludos.

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent Muchas gracias por tu aporte, estaré investigando los otros 2 métodos porque de echo ya utilizo el método GET para hacer cambios de páginas, con el fin que si desean adicionar una nueva página sea solamente una única vez, te agradezco por contestar.

Comment: no te preocupes para eso estamos. saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siguiendo con  la misma lógica deberías agregar un elemento `html`  `<a>` con el atributo `href` que apunte a la pagina de detalle  y pasar por parámetro el `id_producto`

```html
 <?php while($rowpro = $rproduct->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ ?>
         <div class="col-md-3">
           <!--Esta es la etiqueta nueva -->
          <a href="direccionAdetalle.php?id=<?php echo $rowpro['id_properso']; ?>">
            <div class="card <?php if($rowpro['id_properso'] != NULL || $row['id_properso'] != ''){ echo "card-outline card-warning";}?>">
               <a href="#" id="btneditFotopro" value="<?php echo $rowpro['id_producto']; ?>">
                  <img class="card-img-top" src="../data/bodega/Productos/<?php if($rowpro['imagen_producto'] == NULL){echo 'default.png';}else{echo $rowpro['imagen_producto'];}?>" onmouseout="this.src='../data/bodega/Productos/<?php if($rowpro['imagen_producto'] == NULL){echo 'default.png';}else{echo $rowpro['imagen_producto'];}?>';" onmouseover="this.src='../assets/img/edit.png';">
               </a>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title"><strong><?php echo $rowpro['nombre_producto'] ?></strong></h5>
                  <p class="card-text" style="font-size:15px">
                     <?php echo $rowpro['descripcion_producto'] ?>
                     </br>
                     <h5><span class="badge badge-info">Q.<?php echo $rowpro['precio_producto'];?>.00</span></h5>
                  </p>
               </div>
            </div>
             <!--Recuerda cerrar la etiqueta -->
            </a>
         </div>
<?php } ?>
```

En la pagina destino debes obtener el id_producto mediante la variable `GET`

```html
<?php

$id = $_GET["id"] ;


obtenemos los datos de ese producto
$product = "SELECT id_producto, nombre_producto, descripcion_producto, precio_producto, imagen_producto, id_properso FROM PRODUCTO WHERE id_producto = $id";
$rproduct = $con -> query($product);
?>
```

Documentación:

- [Pasar parámetros URL](https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/317.php)
- [GET](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.get.php)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me fue muy útil, lo estaba probando con el método POST pero creo que este esta mejor. Muchas gracias:)